# How to groupby column name and join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I have an excel sheet given to me that looks like this that is a lot longer:

[Original Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYME4.png)

I have to import it into Access and it absolutely requires the format to look like:

[Desired Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGiT3.png)

So I imported it:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(r"XXX")
df
```

Transposed it.

```
df.T
```

I know I have to use:

```
pandas.DataFrame.groupby
```

How do I groupby headers with the same name without manually defining each one as there is too many categories on the real version?

EDITED: Provided pictures for clarification.

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I tried using ASCII art earlier but didn't work so I inserted some pictures instead.

Comment: Data in text is always better than Images.

Comment: how are you matching food to an animal and a country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `groupby()` one way is:

```
m=df.groupby('CATEGORY')['CHOICE'].apply(list)
n=pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist()).T
n.columns=m.index
n=n.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
n=n.reindex(df.CATEGORY.unique(),axis=1)
```

---

```
        Food Animal Country
0  Chocolate    Cat     USA
1      Bread    Dog   Japan
2      Apple   None  France
3   Sandwich   None    None
4       Cake   None    None
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution absolutely worked. I suppose it's nitpicking but is there a way to preserve the order it came in instead of alphabetically?